# Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Failure sending mail."

Tags: sql-server, powershell, email, outlook, sql-server-agent

I've want to send mail from SQL Server. I have tried with Google account with the below mentioned  Windows PowerShell Codes and it's been working perfectly.

**Google account script:**

```
$EmailTo = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com"
$EmailFrom = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com"
$Subject = "Test"
$Body = "Test Body"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxxxx@gmail.com", "MyPassword"); 
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```

but I have need to change the script to my office email id (microsoft account id), So I've changed the script as I written below and and It's also working perfectly.

**Microsoft account script (Outlook):**

```
$EmailTo = "xxxxxxxxx@office.co.in"
$EmailFrom = "xxxxxxxxx@office.co.in"
$Subject = "Test"
$Body = "Test Body"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.office365.com"
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxxxxxx@office.co.in", "MyPassword"); 
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```

Whenever I tried this code on my machine it's working fine, but I shared the same code to office machine. The Google account code working fine and I received the mails too. But the Microsoft account code is not working properly it gives some errors and not able to receive the mail.

**Error:**

> Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Failure sending mail."

Comment: What OS version is the server? If it is Server 2012 or below, have you installed the correct updates and registry settings for TLS 1.2?

Comment: Typed as query in SQL `SELECT @@Version`.                                                      
    and got some results for the Version:-                   
                                                                              
                                                                                    
     `Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64) 
 Apr 29 2016 23:23:58 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: )`

Comment: Is the server fully up to date with latest Windows updates?

Comment: Dear @Charlieface, The issue has been resolved now, Thank you for the valuable answer and your time